# How to mock dependency of a third party dependency with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking

I have imported a third party component:

```
// Third party dependency
import { useCustomContextHook } from 'dependency-of-dependency';

export function ImportedThirdPartyComponent(props) {
   
   const context = useCustomContextHook();

   ...
```

I have my component which uses the third party component:

```
// my component
import { ImportedThirdPartyDependency } from 'third-party-dependency';

function MyComponent(props) {
   ...
   
   return <div>
      <ImportedThirdPartyDependency props={...} />
      ...
   </div>
```

In the test file for my own component, how can I mock out the `useCustomContextHook`?
Should I/how can I stub out the entire `ImportedThirdPartyDependency` component instead?